# Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CN

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I have installed nexus repository ( nexus-3.0.2-02 ) in a red hat machine.
In nexus startup it gives the following error.

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CN
  at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.node.KeyStoreManagerImpl.<init>(KeyStoreManagerImpl.java:39)
  at / (via modules: org.sonatype.nexus.extender.modules.NexusBundleModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.space.SpaceModule)
  while locating org.sonatype.nexus.internal.node.KeyStoreManagerImpl
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
  while locating org.sonatype.nexus.ssl.KeyStoreManager annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=node)
    for parameter 0 at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.node.LocalNodeAccessImpl.<init>(LocalNodeAccessImpl.java:54)
  at / (via modules: org.sonatype.nexus.extender.modules.NexusBundleModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.space.SpaceModule)
  while locating org.sonatype.nexus.internal.node.LocalNodeAccessImpl
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
  while locating org.sonatype.nexus.common.node.LocalNodeAccess
    for parameter 1 at org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.QuartzSchedulerSPI.<init>(QuartzSchedulerSPI.java:111)
  at / (via modules: org.sonatype.nexus.extender.modules.NexusBundleModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.space.SpaceModule)
  while locating org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.QuartzSchedulerSPI
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
  while locating org.sonatype.nexus.scheduling.spi.SchedulerSPI
    for parameter 0 at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.scheduling.SchedulerCapability.<init>(SchedulerCapability.java:38)
  while locating org.sonatype.nexus.internal.scheduling.SchedulerCapability
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025) [na:na]
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162) [na:na]
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81) [na:na]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.capability.DefaultCapabilityFactoryRegistry$1.create(DefaultCapabilityFactoryRegistry.java:113) [na:na]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.capability.DefaultCapabilityRegistry.create(DefaultCapabilityRegistry.java:359) [na:na]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.capability.DefaultCapabilityRegistry.add(DefaultCapabilityRegistry.java:142) [na:na]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.capability.CapabilityBooterSupport.addCapability(CapabilityBooterSupport.java:94) [na:na]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.capability.CapabilityBooterSupport.maybeAddCapability(CapabilityBooterSupport.java:60) [na:na]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.scheduling.SchedulerCapabilityBooter.boot(SchedulerCapabilityBooter.java:34) [na:na]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.capability.CapabilityBooterSupport.handle(CapabilityBooterSupport.java:41) [na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74) [com.google.guava:18.0.0]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47) [com.google.guava:18.0.0]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322) [com.google.guava:18.0.0]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.ReentrantEventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(ReentrantEventBus.java:62) [com.google.guava:18.0.0]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275) [com.google.guava:18.0.0]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.event.EventBusImpl.post(EventBusImpl.java:81) [org.sonatype.nexus.common:3.0.2.02]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.capability.CapabilityRegistryBooter.doStart(CapabilityRegistryBooter.java:67) [org.sonatype.nexus.core:3.0.2.02]
    at org.sonatype.goodies.lifecycle.LifecycleSupport.start(LifecycleSupport.java:104) [org.sonatype.goodies.lifecycle:2.1.0]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.startComponent(NexusLifecycleManager.java:154) [org.sonatype.nexus.extender:3.0.2.02]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.to(NexusLifecycleManager.java:94) [org.sonatype.nexus.extender:3.0.2.02]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener.frameworkEvent(NexusContextListener.java:214) [org.sonatype.nexus.extender:3.0.2.02]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1429) [org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308) [org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CN
    at org.sonatype.nexus.ssl.CertificateUtil.generateCertificate(CertificateUtil.java:87) [na:na]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.ssl.internal.geronimo.FileKeystoreInstance.generateCertificate(FileKeystoreInstance.java:845) [na:na]
```

I have no idea why this happen and i have search in internet for better solution.
But i wasn't found any answer for this issue.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like the keystores under $DATA_DIR/keystores/ssl/ may be corrupt.  You can shut down nexus and remove them, they will get recreated.

Comment: I have remove keystores under $DATA_DIR/keystores/ssl/.but still error occured as in the earlier time.